# I want to disable a checkbox when another checkbox is clicked in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I want to click a check box and have another linked check box be disabled in Excel.

When I uncheck that particular check box, then the disabled check box should become enabled.

I tried so many things but not able to find the solution. Can I do this without a script?

I have 76 check boxes to work upon. So is this possible without a script? TIA

Comment: By 'locked', do you mean disabled?

Comment: Yes, by locked i mean disabled. thanks

Comment: I forgot to mention one thing. can i do this without a script? I have 76 check boxes to work upon. so is this possible without a script? TIA

Answer (score 1):

With two ActiveX check boxes the code would be:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()

If CheckBox2.Enabled = True Then
    CheckBox2.Enabled = False
Else:
    CheckBox2.Enabled = True
End If

End Sub
```

It's simple, but works.

Comment: Thanks for the answer...I forgot to mention one thing. can i do this without a script? I have 76 check boxes to work upon. so is this possible without a script? TIA

Answer (score 1):

If you want the code to check and disable clicking on the second box, use the below code. If you uncheck the initial box, it will also enable and uncheck the second one.

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
    CheckBox2.Value = True
    CheckBox2.Enabled = False
Else
    CheckBox2.Value = False
    CheckBox2.Enabled = True
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer...I forgot to mention one thing. can i do this without a script? I have 76 check boxes to work upon. so is this possible without a script? TIA

Comment: @SangeetaMishra, you're most likely going to have to use code if you want the checkboxes to work automatically.

Answer (score 1):

more directly

```
Sub CheckBox1_Click()
 CheckBox2.Enabled = Not CheckBox2.Enabled
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I belive you could use "OptionButton's". You don't need code for them. But in that way you'll be able to check only one of 76.  And what do you mean by "linked check box"?

Comment: linked check box means if i enable one, another should be disabled

Comment: This would do what you need, but as I say, you can have only one optionButton(checkBox) checked, of all 76. If you find this answer usefull, please mark it or wote up.

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Ck1_Click()

If Ck1 = True Then
Ck2.Enabled = False
Ck3.Enabled = False
Else
Ck2.Enabled = True
Ck3.Enabled = True
End If

End Sub

Private Sub Ck2_Click()

If Ck2 = True Then
Ck1.Enabled = False
Ck3.Enabled = False
Else
Ck1.Enabled = True
Ck3.Enabled = True
End If

End Sub

Private Sub Ck3_Click()

If Ck3 = True Then
Ck1.Enabled = False
Ck2.Enabled = False
Else
Ck1.Enabled = True
Ck2.Enabled = True
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Note:  Using MSAccess 2010, On Click event.
There are three checkboxes, Ck1, Ck2, & Ck3. If you click on Ck1, Ck2 & Ck3 are disabled.  If you click on Ck2, Ck1 & Ck3 are disabled.  If you click on Ck3, Ck1 & Ck2 are disabled.  Unchecking any of them enables the other two fields.

Comment: Please add explanation also about what your code does and how.